# Create a Map<Key,Object> based on a List<Object> - Converting Loops into Java streams

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

Facing error while converting a `List<Object>` to a `HashMap<Key,Object>`.

I can do with a traditional code, but I'm getting an error while doing using Java 8 streams and ignore the duplicate keys.

*Equivalent code:*

```java
Map<String, Field> uniqueFields = new HashMap<>();
for (Field field : allFields) {
    uniqueFields.put(field.getName(), field);
}
```

Tried below stream, but there's a syntactic mistake:

```java
Map<String, Field> uniqueFields1 = allFields.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Field::getName, 
        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue));
```

Comment: You missed the key value like (Field::getName, Field::getXXX, (oldValue,newValue)->oldValue))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need one more argument to the `toMap` function to tell the collector what should be the values of the `Map`. You can use `Function.identity()`, which means it will just pass the `Field` right through.

```
 Map<String,Field> uniqueFields = allFields.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::getName, Function.identity(), 
        (oldValue,newValue) -> oldValue));
```

Comment: Getting syntax error in Function " Function cannot be resolved" , @marstran

Comment: It working , issue was with import Fixed that Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The flavor of `Collectors.toMap()`, that expects two arguments, should be provided with `Function`s: *keyMapper* and *valueMapper* (that are responsible for expracting a *key* and a *value* respectivelly from a stream element).

But in your code snippet, the second argument isn't of type `Function`, because you've provided two arguments `oldValue, newValue`, but `Function` takes only one.

You need to use a version of `toMap` that in addition to *keyMapper* and *valueMapper* functions expects the third argument `BinaryOperator` *mergeFunction* which is meant to resolve *values* mapped to the same *key*:

```
Map<String, Field> uniqueFields = allFields.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Field::getName,      // generating a kay
        Function.identity(), // generating a value
        (oldValue, newValue) -> oldValue))); // resolving duplicates
```

Comment: Error "Function cannot be resolved"

Comment: @ShaliniGupta which expression causes the error?

Comment: Its working Thanks , issue was with import Function